Why isn't 127.0.0.1 in a list of known hostnames by default?
I was running an ansible script on a huge inventory of hosts, the inventory contained the IP address of the ansible control node itself, let's say 10.1.1.1
So naturally a bizarre situation happened: the control node tried to log in to itself. It succeded of course but only after this prompt.
The authenticity of host '127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.

Now I know what this prompt means and why it appears, but it made me curious.
Why isn't 127.0.0.1 (along with its key fingerprint) in a list of known hostnames by default?

Your tags have SSH. Is Ansible using an SSH transport and the question is about that?

@DanielB Yep, ansible is using ssh to connect to hosts, but it isn't about that. It's what led to me to ask this question: Why isn't 127.0.0.1 in a list of known hostnames by default? Ansible is irrelevant here, it's just what made me wonder about this.

not all systems need to have a 127.0.0.1 address (though I am guessing most modern systems require a loopback). admins are free to assign any address from the 127.0.0.0 block.

@DrMoishePippik It certainly has public keys, in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*.pub. They are world-readable.

@FrankThomas it does have a 127.0.0.1 address, don't think my host is an exception in this behaviour though, hence the question.

@GetTwoBirdsStonedAtOnce, My point was that because of this uncertainty, it makes sense that the ssh devs choose to do nothing rather than something, like auto-provisioning a hostname entry.

@FrankThomas I get what you're saying. If that's the case, it should be possible to run a check for this. Since Linux is open source, I might even try to contribute that bit or open an issue.
